# Defining sympy.abc variables on the fly : name error handling

Tags: python, error-handling, sympy

I am trying to evaluate with `eval` SymPy expressions which can contain any of the abc letters :

```
from sympy.abc import *
```

I want to implement inside a method a way of handling NameError by defining the relevant variables on the fly. Here is the gist of it

```
try:
    eval(expr)
except NameError as err:
    msg = str(err)
    pos = msg.find("'")
    letter = msg[pos+1]
    from sympy.abc import letter
```

Obviously there is no letter in sympy.abc called letter. So that will raise an exception. Another issue is that if a symbol like theta is used, then only the first letter of this symbol is evaluated. So any tips on how I can first of all manage to import the value of letter, and perhaps also handle symbols like eta, phi, etc.

Another important issue is that there can be many different letters in the expression. How can I handle that?

**Edit** : I have managed to almost solve the problem.
Here is my attempt at it :

```
def try_expr(expr):
    try:
        eval(expr)
    except NameError as err:
        msg = str(err)
        pos = msg.find("'")
        letter = msg[pos+1]
        pos = pos +1
        found = False
        while (pos+1 < len(msg)) and (not found):
            more = msg[pos+1]
            for symb in symbols:
                if more==symb or more.isdigit():
                    found = True
                    break
                if found is False:
                    letter = letter+more       
                    pos = pos + 1
        for alphabet in abc.__dict__:
            if letter == alphabet:
                exec('from sympy.abc import %s'%alphabet)
                letters.append(alphabet)
                try_expr(expr) # try to evaluate the expression again
import sympy.abc as abc
symbols = ['*','/','(',')',"'"]
letters = [] # for storing any letters that are in the expression
try_expr('2*theta')
```

I have managed to import the first unknown variable from sympy.abc (regardless if it is single char letter or a greek alphabet like 'theta'. Yet, when I try to recursively call upon the function to find any other unknowns, the letter I have managed to import is raised again as unknown. In the process, I end up getting a `RuntimeError : maximum recursion depth exceeded while getting the str of an object`.

Comment: The whole point behind this is to avoid calling `from sympy.abc import * `. I simply do not want to pollute the users namespace.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't just use `sympify()`?

Comment: I need to substitute some of the variables at a later point. But you are right, one call to simplify, and all the code above becomes useless.

Comment: SymPy also has some lower level functions for parsing expressions (take a look at sympy.parsing) which could be helpful as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code, with a run example

```
import sympy.abc as abc
symbols = ['*','/','(',')',"'",'"']
letters = []
def try_expr(expr):
    try:
        for letter in letters:
            exec('from sympy.abc import %s'%letter) # re-execute after finding each unknown variable
        l = expr.count('(')
        r = expr.count(')')
        if l == r:         
            eval(expr)
        elif l < r:
            eval((r-l)*'('+expr)
    except NameError as err:
        msg = str(err)
        pos = msg.find("'")
        letter = msg[pos+1]
        pos = pos +1
        found = False
        while (pos+1 < len(msg)) and (not found): # check for multi-char greek letters
            more = msg[pos+1]
            for symb in symbols:
                if more==symb or more.isdigit():
                    found = True
                    break
            if found is False:
                letter = letter+more       
                pos = pos + 1
        for alphabet in abc.__dict__:
            if letter == alphabet:
                letters.append(alphabet)
                try_expr(expr[expr.find(alphabet):]) # search for the next unknown variable

from sympy import sin, sqrt, log, exp, cos, tanh, sinh, cosh, atan, acos, asin
import sys
if len(sys.argv) == 1:
    expr = '(sin(x**2)-log(exp(2*y))) + cos(x**2) + a + b + c + theta*eta'
else:
    expr = sys.argv[1]
try_expr(expr)
for letter in letters:
    exec('from sympy.abc import %s'%letter)
print 'The SymPy expression %s contains the following letters : %s' %(eval('%s'%expr), letters)
```

**Edit**: Added a fix for unbalanced paranthesis when the expression is evaluated after it has been split.

Comment: From not wanting to pollute the namespace (by simply using `from sympy.abc import *`), to having this as a solution, I do not know what is worse.